# is possible to unpivot a sql server table using headers as a column and values as another column?

Tags: sql, transpose, unpivot

I have a table like this:

| TableName | dates | ModelName | BaseUnitPerPallet | pallet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Calendar | June | Null | 4 | 1 |
| Country | June | Null | 2 | 6 |
| Product | June | DOWNSTREAM | Null | 8 |
| ProductBOM | June | DOWNSTREAM | 9 | 9 |

and I want a table like this:

| Columns | values |
| --- | --- |
| TableName | Calendar |
| TableName | Country |
| TableName | Product |
| TableName | ProductBOM |

where columns field is the headers of the previous table, and values are the values in an unpivot way.

I have been trying without success the unpivot logic:

```
SELECT Columns, Values
FROM
(
SELECT  TableName, dates, ModelName, BaseUnitPerPallet, pallet
FROM Database
as source_query
)
UNPIVOT
(
Values FOR Columns IN ( TableName, dates, ModelName, BaseUnitPerPallet, pallete)
)
as pivot_results
```

any advice or guidance would be great.
Additionally, any resource to do this dinamic? and apply the logic without write the column names?

Thanks in advance¡

Comment: Based on your desired results what relevance are the other columns dates/ModelName/BaseUnitPerPallet/pallet in your sample table?

Comment: My desired results are sample results, after tableName would go the other columns dates/ModelName /BaseUnitPerPallet/pallet

Comment: The pivot/unpivot statments are limited and unwieldy (imho) it's easier to use *cross apply* and *values*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using APPLY to unpivot your table

### Unpivot using APPLY

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #YourTable
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (
     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,TableName VARCHAR(100)
    ,Dates Varchar(25)
    ,ModelName VARCHAR(100)
    ,BaseUnitPerPallet TINYINT
    ,Pallet TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO #YourTable
VALUES 
('Calendar','June',NULL,4,1)
,('Country','June',NULL,2,6)
,('Product','June','DOWNSTREAM',NULL,8)
,('ProductBOM','June','DOWNSTREAM',9,9)

SELECT A.ID,B.*
FROM #YourTable AS A
CROSS APPLY 
    (VALUES 
        ('TableName',A.TableName)
        ,('Dates',A.Dates)  
        ,('ModelName',A.ModelName)  
        ,('BaseUnitPerPallet',CAST(A.BaseUnitPerPallet AS Varchar(100)))
        ,('Pallet',CAST(A.Pallet AS Varchar(100)))  
    ) AS B(ColumnName,Val)
--WHERE B.Val IS NOT NULL /*Optional in case you want to ignore NULLs*/
ORDER BY A.ID,B.ColumnName
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was just was I was looking for¡ Sorry for the beginner question¡